# program crashes when attempting to set the value of a string issue with cin >>

Tags: c++, string, cin

This is a bizarre error that I have never seen before, and do not know how to fix it. The crash occurs on

`na = m`

Here is the relevant code. The line in question is marked with *:

In Main:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "stu.h"
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    stu stu;
    int score[2];

    std::string name;
    std::cout <<"enter name:";
    std::cin >> name;
     //THIS IS AN EDIT IN  AFTER SEEING THAT A IMPORTANT ERROR POINT WAS NOT SHOWN TO THE FIRST COUPLE REPLY 
       ************************************************************
     //THIS IS CAUSING THE PROBLEM WHEN I COMMENT IT OUT THE PROGRAM WORKS 
     std::cout << "enter score 1:";
     std::cin >> score[0];
     std::cout << "enter score 2:";
     std::cin >> score[2];
     std::cout << "enter score 3:";
     std::cin >> score[3];
      *************************************************************
    stu.setname( name );

    // ...
}
```

In `stu.ccp`:

```
void stu::setname(std::string m)
{
    std::cout <<"1";//<--to find where the code was crashing 

    na = m; // *** the crash

    std::cout <<"1";
}
```

In `stu.hpp`:

```
class stu
#include <string>
{
public:
    stu();
    void setname(std::string);
    std::string getname();
    void settest(int, int,int);
    void display();

private:
    std::string na;

    int score[2];   
};
```

Comment: Proper indentation is totally overrated.

Comment: Are you accessing an instance of class stu through any pointer (somewhere else in you code)?

Comment: You should provide some minimal code sample that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Also - including a file between the class and it's curly brackets? this can't be good

Comment: When do you declare `na`?

Comment: @Chemistpp its in his class stu. hard to see with this indentation

Comment: I moved the line `#include <string>` to the top of the file _stu.h_ and it ran fine. (adding also the constructor implementation)

Comment: 1. Does the code as posted compile on your machine. 2. What do you mean by "crash" - do you get some kind of error?

Comment: Oh, yep my bad, there it is.  It seems like n would be in an invalid state

Comment: Please don't provide "relevant code". Please provide a short, complete program that compiles and demonstrates the error you are seeing. See http://SSCCE.ORG for more information.

Answer (score 1):

When you define `int score[2]` you get an array of 2 `int` and the valid array indices are `0..1`.

Your later code writes past the end of the array and trashes whatever follows it in memory, in this case the string object `name`.

```
std::cout << "enter score 1:";
std::cin >> score[0];
std::cout << "enter score 2:";
std::cin >> score[2];
std::cout << "enter score 3:";
std::cin >> score[3];
```

The last two array references are incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You allocated enough space for two integers in an array, having valid indices `0` and `1`.

```
 int score[2];
```

Then you tried to read more elements than that

```
 std::cin >> score[2];
 std::cout << "enter score 3:";
 std::cin >> score[3];
```

This is undefined behavior and *anything* is allowed to happen, including your entire computer disappearing in a fireball.  In your case, it overwrote the memory next to the array, which was your `string` variable.  Making a copy of a corrupted string can easily crash the program.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code, it compiles and also runs with no problem.

Except for what you've provided I've just defined also the constructor, moved `#include <string>` before `class stu` in `stu.h` and removed that `std::cout << "1"`.

Comment: Both std::cout << "1" lines? Or just the first one? See, I don't think we've got the real probelm code.

Answer (score 0):

```
int score [2]
```

will only have score[0] and score [1] spots for values. use 
Try

```
   int score[3]
```

Then store your values in

```
 score[0];
 score[1];
 score[2];
```